# Suggestion on approach to compare XMLs (instead of using regex with Java's String replaceAll)

Tags: java, regex, xml, xml-parsing, compare

I'm writing a test utility that I intend to use to create artificial traffic to the main application (a Spring Integration based application that has entry points in both JMS  based and SOAP services downstream and upstream). 
In addition to creating the traffic I want to be able to tell if the application is responding properly (i.e. taking an XML and comparing against a predetermined expected value). I have base XMLs for the different types of responses, but there are dynamic values that based on the situation I need to manipulate to be able to compare against the base source for comparison. 
One way to solve it: using the [replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method of the `String` Java class, where I manipulate both source and target XMLs as needed to a logical point where I can determine if the response is valid or not.
I'm interested to know if there is any XML utility framework that provides a more advance set of capabilities to achieve this?
Many thanks

Comment: If you're trying to assert against xml data in tests you could try using an xml matching library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the "replace" normalization using an XSLT transformation, then use the XPath 2.0 deep-equal() function (perhaps within the same transformation) to do the comparison with reference results. This enables proper XML comparison semantics, e.g. ignoring insignificant whitespace, or arbitrary distinctions such as single-versus-double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You could generate jaxb classs for your xml, unmarshal it, and then check the properties of interest. Chances are you already have those classes as your dom objects for your JMS and WS logic, so maybe they need only @XMLRoot anotation on top.

To stay closer to xml, you could use XPath to extract the dynamic bits that you expect.